# jenkins selenium do not run test headlessly

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, service, headless-browser

I am running pytests selenium tests using jenkins. I ran test on my local machine it works. But when I run through jenkins, it runs on remote jenkins machine(creates workspace on remote jenkins machine) headlessly and it fails with test errors such as 'element not visible' or 'timeout exception due to element not clickable'. 
After this I ran test on remote machine directly (windows server) in workspace. It launches chrome browser and runs test and passes.

1. Why is it running test headlessly when run through jenknis?
2. Can I make it to force open browser while running through jenkins?
3. Why tests are failing when ran through jenkins headlessly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your Jenkins is running as service on that machine under Windows, there are 2 things you may want to try at this point:

1. Specify local system account in service and check allow service to interact with desktop. More on how to do it in [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson8/). However, it could result in other issues.
2. Run your jenkins instance from [WAR file](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins), case you're running your tests on slave machine: start jenkins slave from command line.

Comment: option 1 doesn't launch browser. Is it mandatory to run war file through cmd? I just want to launch browser when I run tests

Comment: 1. Have you tried launching service with your account and checkbox checked as well?
2. Like I said I think that main problem here is that you're running Jenkins as service, another thing you may try is to establish grid\node on this machine and use RemoteWebDriver

Comment: i guess there is no way if we just run jenkins as service. I had to run war file from command line, then it launches browser.